# Mostrar informacion desde un datepicker

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datepicker

les cuento que con mis casi nulos conocimientos de programacion estoy terminando de armar un sitio para mi negocio, ahora quede trabado con un datepicker, ya esta todo configurado pero me resta poder mostrar informacion cuando el usuario selecciona una fecha que le interese ver, yo quiero mostrar resultados de loteria en cada uno de los dias del almanaque y esos resultados los voy guardando yo en otras paginas, entonces quisiera traer la info de esas paginas a traves del datepicker.
No se si sera muy comlicado o muy simple, pero no logro dar en la tecla, alguno me podra dar una mano ??

Comment: Y que has intentado? Sin código es difícil ayudarte.

Comment: la verdad es que no se por donde empezar, yo baje los archivos jquery , pase todo a español y pude agregar el datepicker en mi pagina, pero ahora necesito asociar cierta informacion al datepicker

Comment: por lo que estyuve leyendo deberia usar ajax y traer la informacion que quiero mostrar

Comment: "Empieza por el principio -dijo el Rey con gravedad- y sigue hasta llegar al final; allí te paras"